# ¿Cómo solucionar este error? Invalid Character Constant en Java

Tags: java, eclipse, validación, texto

Tengo que migrar unos servicios SOAP a REST en Java, pero tengo un problema con un archivo, en ejecución no genera ningún problema pero en el IDE me arroja un error grave.

Resulta que tengo la siguiente declaración:

```
private static final char[] CHARACTERS_SANITIZE = new char[] {'Ã¡','Ã©','Ã­','Ã³','Ãº','Ã�','Ã‰','Ã�','Ã“','Ãš','Ã±','Ã‘'};
```

Esto para ejecutar el siguiente método

```
public static String sanearAcentosyTildes(String str) {
        int length = str.length();
        char[] chString = str.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < CHARACTERS_SANITIZE.length; i++) {
            char _character = CHARACTERS_SANITIZE[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                if (chString[j] == _character) {
                    chString[j] = CHARACTERS_REPLACE[i];
                }
            }
        }
        return new String(chString);
}
```

Pero la línea de la declaración me arroja este error

```
Invalid character constant
```

He intentado de todo para solucinarlo, he cambiado en la codificación a UTF8, he intentado establecerlo entre `" "` pero me tira otro error de datos, porque se convierte en string y yo lo necesito manejar como char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Puedes probar a sustituir tus caracteres especiales por [esta codificación](https://www.indalcasa.com/programacion/html/tabla-de-codificaciones-de-caracteres-entre-ansi-utf-8-javascript-html/) la que corresponde a la columna de Javascript que es la de Unicode?

Quedando algo así:

```
//'Ã­','Ã³','Ãº','Ã�','Ã‰','Ã�','Ã“','Ãš','Ã±','Ã\‘'
private static final char[] CHARACTERS_SANITIZE = 
                new char[] {'\u00e1','\u00e9', '\u00fa'};
```

Sería completarlo para el resto. Yo lo he probado y no me da ningún error, pero con la otra codificación que tenías tú definida inicialmente, sí.

Incluyo el resto del código:

```
package principal;


public class Principal {

    //'Ã­','Ã³','Ãº','Ã�','Ã‰','Ã�','Ã“','Ãš','Ã±','Ã\‘'
    private static final char[] CHARACTERS_SANITIZE = 
                new char[] {'\u00e1','\u00e9', '\u00fa'};
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
       // Aquí invocarías sanearACentosyTildes

        
    }
    
    public static String sanearAcentosyTildes(String str) {
        int length = str.length();
        char[] chString = str.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < CHARACTERS_SANITIZE.length; i++) {
            char _character = CHARACTERS_SANITIZE[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                if (chString[j] == _character) {
                    chString[j] = CHARACTERS_REPLACE[i];
                }
            }
        }
        return new String(chString);
    }   
    
    
}
```

Comment: Gracias padaleina.

Comment: Excelente! Esto funciono para mí!